# Switch form Widget - GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have add an `Gridview` with `Imageview`, `TextView`. It is working perfectly fine. Now i want to add `on/off` button . I choose Switch. It is also working fine. I need to set click/checkchanged action. But i face one issue.

First i tried with `onCheckChanged` Listener It is working. But the problem was when i try to scroll `GridView` checkchanged Listener called.

So

I try to another option `onclick` Listener. It is also working. Here the problem was when i swipe switch click action not triggered.

I try another one option. That is `onTouch` Listener. It is not working. The reason was when i touch action called multiple times.

How to `handle switch in GridView`? Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that is disable switch. 
Little bit confusing . But the solution was

**Step 1:**

Implement setOnTouchListener

ex:

```
switchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
  }
});
```

**Step 2:**

After step 1. We are free to implement onclickListener.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use form `checkBox` :

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(etc.....);
chk.setOnClickLictenetr(new oclickLictener(){
    @Override
    public void onclick(View view){
       CheckBox chekbox = (CheckBox) view;
for example this is your structure===> item.done = chekbox.isChecked();
    }
});
```

If you scrolling , you will have your checked.

Comment: It will work that is i mention in my question. But here the problem is when i swipe switch there is no action (onclick) triggered

Comment: Ok . You can see this link , perhaps help you : [Click Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Configuration-Changes)

Comment: What is the relation between my question and that link. I don't understand what you mean